# How remove add-in outlook programmatically?

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I already have installed add-in outlook. I need create other add-in outlook that will check exist new version first add-in outlook on some server, if exist new version than need remove old version and install new version. I do not know how remove and install add-in programmatically (use other add-in). How I сan remove or install?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove the corresponding entry from the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins and HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins

Comment: It is work,add-in dissapear  from outlook but  in directory "C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\" remain dll add-in and in windows menu "Remove and Update" so remain. Can I fully remove add-in?